# How to convert a Number to Current Locale in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

how can I convert a number to current `Locale`, as some countries are using commas "," instead of periods "."

For example this number:

```swift
var number = 1.5
```

the end result should be this, as commas "," are only allowed in strings:

```swift
var number = "1,5"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why there is NumberFormatter. Use it for *all* user-facing strings that represent numbers. This is an artificial demonstration:

```
let num = 1.5
let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .decimal
nf.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
let s = nf.string(from: num as NSNumber) // 1.5

nf.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
let s2 = nf.string(from: num as NSNumber) // 1,5
```

Why artificial? Because in real life, you do *not* set the `locale` of the NumberFormatter. It has the user's locale *automatically*. Problem solved.

Comment: it doesn't work with all numbers. the number 5500.0 is in the locale en_US 5,500 which is clearly not correct

Comment: Actually, it is correct. In English we do use comma separators between thousands. The reason you're not seeing the result you expect is that you have not set enough of the number formatter's properties. Want to suppress thousands commas? Want to guarantee a certain number of digits after the decimal point? There are properties for those, and many more. Try reading the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter